# Detect if mouse is outside of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover

I made a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RrxpT/

So the red box needs to be placed over the blue boxes when mouse is on top of them. As you can see it works, but I also want the red box to be hidden if it's not on top on any of the blue boxes.

I changed the code to:

```
if(box.is(':hover')){
  // put red box on top
}else{
  // hide red box
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RrxpT/1/

But it doesn't work very well :s

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Have a look at mouseenter and mouseout.  What kind of "hidden" do you want?  Your example shows it goint back to 0,0,0,0 or do you want it to completely hide and then reappear from 0,0,0,0 when another box is hovered on?

Comment: yes i just want it back to 0,0, with 0 width and height

Comment: @Alex - you want the overlay to animate away on mouseleave like this? http://jsfiddle.net/RrxpT/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I've understood the question correctly then I would stop using `mousemove` and instead delegate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers to elements that should trigger the overlay:

```
$("body").on("mouseenter", ".Box", function () {
    // Show the overlay
}).on("mouseleave", ".Box", function () {
    // Hide the overlay
});
```

Because the overlay is then on top of the element it will not work nicely when you move the mouse around within the element itself. To resolve this you can add a CSS property to the overlay:

```css
#over {
    /* ... */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RrxpT/2/).

Comment: thanks :D but if I add pointer-events: none it seems I cannot click on links from my red box